# Learning C# ASAP to get started with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have experience writing web apps in Django; scripting in Python; playing with PHP and I understand Object Oriented Programming. I need to get started ASAP with C# in order to start learning and using ASP.NET for a clients project.

Is there a way to get a working knowledge of C# without passing by the over-a-thousand-pages-books? How should I proceed to gain that knowledge?

Thanks.

Comment: this is an unsolicited plug for ASP.NET 2.0 Website Programming: Problem - Design - Solution the book - it was how i learned ASP.NET a while back and it really gets to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the project, of course, but given your programming background you'll be learning more about the intricacies of ASP.NET and the "how to's" of C#.  In other words, you've already got a good jump start.

I'd recommend focusing on learning ASP.NET as most examples are in C# and you'll get the idea along the way.

This might also help:  The first few chapters of Beginning ASP.NET 4 are available here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg697787(v=vs.88).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you have the prior knowledge you say you do with OOP, Python, and PHP...C# should be incredibly easy for you to pick up.

It's incredibly similar to Java in syntax, so if you know any of that you're basically good already.

I quickly read through [these](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx) when I got started with C# and I was able to pick it up very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

It's as good of a lanuage to get started with OO programming as any.  Incidentally, I don't find ASP.NET to be overly OO, compared to alot of things, so for a speedy approach I'd take a reverse engineer successively more complicated examples, and good place to find them is in the tutorials on http://www.asp.net

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the good books for C# since you are already familiar with OOPS concept.

C# via CLR
C# in depth
C# in a nutshell